# How to prevent vote multiple/fast clicking in Vue exploit?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a vote system that allows the users to vote-up or unvote.

The issue is when a user clicks on the vote button multiple times quickly. It causes the number of upvotes to go up and down in a weird way (It goes up 1,2,3 and then down to below 0, probably has to do with the Vote.vue which adds and subtracts 1's from the total votes so when clicked fast enough it causes this weirdness) .

Also, I took care to have unique questions id and user id in the vote table.

I have these simple vote/unvote methods in the QuestionsController:

```
/**
 * Vote a question up.
 */
public function voteUp(Question $question)
{
    Auth::user()->votes()->attach($question->id);
}

/**
 * Vote a question down.
 */
public function voteDown(Question $question)
{
    Auth::user()->votes()->detach($question->id);
}
```

And maybe more importantly and probably causing the issue is the Vote.vue, as you may see I add/subtract 1 to the total #votes displayed.

```
methods: {
    voteUp(question) {
        axios.post('/voteup/'+question)
            .then(response => this.isVoted = true, this.votes = this.votes + 1)
            .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
    },

    voteDown(question) {
        axios.post('/votedown/'+question)
            .then(response => this.isVoted = false, this.votes = this.votes - 1)
            .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
    }
}
```

How do I overcome this so users won't exploit this + make it behave more stable?

**EDIT: I tried these solutions but it didn't solve the issue:**

**#1** - I tried @Radu Diță solution:

```
<vote 
    :votes="{{ $question->votes()->count() }}"
    :question="{{ $question->id }}"
    :voted="{{ $question->currentUserVoted() ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
    :disabled="voteInAir"
></vote>
```

and the Vote.vue script:

```
// resources/js/components/Vote.vue

<template>
    <span>
        <a href="#" v-if="isVoted" @click.prevent="voteDown(question)">
            <i class="fas fa-caret-up fa-3x text-primary vote-effect vote-up-effect"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="voteUp(question)">
            <i class="fas fa-caret-up fa-3x vote-gray vote-effect"></i>
        </a>
        <span class="vote-count-post "><strong>{{ this.votes }}</strong></span>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['question', 'voted', 'votes'],

        data: function() {
            return {
                isVoted: '',
                voteInAir: false
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.isVoted = this.isVote ? true : false;
        },

        computed: {
            isVote() {
                return this.voted;
            },
        },

        methods: {
            voteUp(question) {
                this.voteInAir = true;
                axios.post('/voteup/'+question)
                    .then(response => this.isVoted = true, this.votes = this.votes + 1, this.voteInAir = false)
                    .catch(response => console.log(response.data), this.voteInAir = false);
            },

            voteDown(question) {
                this.voteInAir = true;
                axios.post('/votedown/'+question)
                    .then(response => this.isVoted = false, this.votes = this.votes - 1, this.voteInAir = false)
                    .catch(response => console.log(response.data), this.voteInAir = false);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**#2** - I also tried @Rijosh solution:

```
<vote 
  :votes="{{ $question->votes()->count() }}"
  :question="{{ $question->id }}"
  :voted="{{ $question->currentUserVoted() ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
></vote>
```

And this is with time interval delay which didnt work:

```
<template>
    <span>
        <a href="#" v-if="isVoted" @click.prevent="voteDown(question)">
            <i class="fas fa-caret-up fa-3x text-primary vote-effect vote-up-effect"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="voteUp(question)">
            <i class="fas fa-caret-up fa-3x vote-gray vote-effect"></i>
        </a>
        <span class="vote-count-post "><strong>{{ this.votes }}</strong></span>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['question', 'voted', 'votes'],

        data: function() {
            return {
                isVoted: '',
                timer: null,
                interval: 200,
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.isVoted = this.isVote ? true : false;
        },

        computed: {
            isVote() {
                return this.voted;
            },
        },

        methods: {
            voteUp(question) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                    axios.post('/voteup/'+question)
                        .then(response => this.isVoted = true, this.votes = this.votes + 1)
                        .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
                }, this.interval);
            },

            voteDown(question) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                    axios.post('/votedown/'+question)
                        .then(response => this.isVoted = false, this.votes = this.votes - 1)
                        .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
                }, this.interval);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Disable the up/down vote button after it's been clicked the first time. You should also use the response from the `QuestionsController` to set `this.votes`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @DigitalDrifter How should I disable it temporarily? (they should be able to unvote..) And how do I get the response in the vue component?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only allowing one vote (or that is what i understand) i would not increase the upvotes directly but make kind of a system with booleans kind of like this:

```
<button v-on:click="activateUpVote">UpVote</button>
<button v-on:click="activateDownVote">DownVote</button>
.
.
.
data(){
  return{
    upVote: false,
    downVote: false,
    hasVoted: false
  }
},
methods: {
  activateUpVote(){
    this.upVote = !this.upVote
    if(this.upVote && (!this.hasVoted || this.downVote)){
      this.downVote = false
      this.hasVoted = true
      this.vote('/votedown/'+this.question, this.votes + 1)
    }else{
      this.hasVoted = false
    }
  },
  //downVote same as above but the other way around except for the hasVoted part          
  vote(route, votes) {
    axios.post(route)
        .then(response => votes)
        .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

> Template

```
    <div>
        <button @click="voteUp">UpVote</button>
        <button @click="voteDown">DownVote</button>
    </div>
```

> Data

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            timer: null,
            interval: 200
        }
    },
```

> Methods

```
    methods: {
        voteUp: function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('up vote')
                // your action
            }, this.interval);
        },

        voteDown: function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('down vote')
                // your action
            }, this.interval);
        }
    }
```

I'm using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` in the methods. This will prevent consecutive actions on the buttons. Continuous clicks will trigger only one action. The time between each click can be controlled using the `interval` value in the `data`.

Comment: hi @Rijosh, thank you very much for writing, I tried it but it didn't work, I put the code in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the button after it was pressed and enabled it again after you get a response. This is usable for any button that you wan't to disable spamming.

In your `data` add a boolean for each button

```
data () {
  return {
    //other data
    upVoteInAir: false
  }
}
```

then bind your button based on the flag

```
<button :disabled="upVoteInAir">Up</button>
```

update the flag based on the http request

```
methods: {
    voteUp(question) {
        this.upVoteInAir = true
        axios.post('/voteup/'+question)
            .then(response => this.isVoted = true, this.votes = this.votes + 1,         this.upVoteInAir = false)
            .catch(response => console.log(response.data),         this.upVoteInAir = false);
    },
}
```

Comment: hi Radu Diță, thank you very much for writing, I tried your solutions but it didn't solve, I added the code I tried in the question, would love to get your feedback.